# Using self.* as default value for a method

Tags: python

```
def save_file(self, outputfilename = self.image_filename): 
    self.file.read(outputfilename)
    ....
```

gives `NameError: name 'self' is not defined` in the first line. It seems that Python doesn't accept it. How can I rewrite the code so it doesn't raise an exception?

Comment: The function definition takes place in a different scope and at a different time.

Comment: Sure would be nice if it did work.  Makes the code a lot cleaner.  I'm guessing it would open some other Pandoran Box to implement?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use a default of `None` and detect that.

```
def save_file(self, outputfilename=None): 
    if outputfilename is None:
        outputfilename = self.image_filename
    self.file.read(outputfilename)
    ....
```

Comment: The problem with this pattern that its misleading.

Answer (score 14):

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html) states:

> Default parameter values are evaluated when the function definition is executed.

This explains why the instance cannot be referenced. As others have said, use None as your default and fix up the value at function execution time when the instance is available.

Answer (score 12):

```
def save_file(self, outputfilename=None): 
    outputfilename = outputfilename or self.image_filename
    self.file.read(outputfilename)
```

or even

```
def save_file(self, outputfilename=None):         
    self.file.read(outputfilename or self.image_filename)
```

This may be nothing with one variable, but if you have, let's say, 5, this makes code easier to read, in my opinion.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it's less verbose than the current one and does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

```
def save_file(self, outputfilename = None):
    if not outputfilename:
        outputfilename = self.image_filename 
    self.file.read(outputfilename)
    ....
```