# Why does doing self in a method definition twice not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

If I'm defining a method on an object:

Why does this:

```
  def forecasts(self, rules = self.rules):
     return rules
```

give a `self` not defined error but:

```
 def forecasts(self, rules=None):                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   if rules is None:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
     rules = self.rules
 return rules
```

work?

Comment: Also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195989/default-values-for-function-parameters-in-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371244/using-self-as-default-value-for-a-method and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131942/python-how-to-pass-default-argument-to-instance-method-with-an-instance-variab

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a default argument that needs to get evaluated when the function is actually defined.

When Python tries to evaluate that function it is going to try and load a name named `self`, look-up an attribute on it. and then set it as the default for `rules`.

You aren't assigning a name for the parameter as you do when you simply use `self` as a positional, you're actually evaluating an expression, `self.rules`, which needs `self` to be defined.