# How to pass reference of a class parameter value to a function default argument value within the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to pass the value supplied to the class parameter to a function in the same class as it's default arguments, so that i could reuse the function to do another calculation with a different parameter value.

> I'm working on creating an ip address calculator as a challenge for me to help learn python programming.

But Pycharm says "Unresolved reference 'self' "

Code:

```
class IPOctet:

    def __init__(self, ip_address, subnet_mask):
        self.ip_address = ip_address
        self.subnet_mask = subnet_mask

    def validate_subnetmask(self, input_subnetmask = self.subnet_mask):
        # this function validates the input_subnetmask value to check if its a numeric value and 
        # returns the value when validated.

        # ...and i want the [input_subnetmask value] to be [self.subnet_mask] as its default arugument
        #  or any value passed into it when called.
```

Comment: Function default values are evaluated at the time the function was originally defined.  The *class* didn't even exist yet, much less any instance of the class to have a meaningful `self` value.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371244/using-self-as-default-value-for-a-method and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131942/how-to-pass-a-default-argument-value-of-an-instance-member-to-a-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use another default value and then check:

```
def validate_subnetmask(self, input_subnetmask=None):
    if input_subnetmask is None:
        input_subnetmask = self.subnet_mask
```

even shorter thanks to @CamiEQ:

```
def validate_subnetmask(self, input_subnetmask=None):
    input_subnetmask = input_subnetmask or self.subnet_mask
```

Comment: you could make it even shorter:
     `input_subnetmask = input_subnetmask or self.subnet_mask`

Comment: ok so do this need an else statement?

Comment: @KwameBenqazy No, just write your code under this function definition.

Comment: @CamiEQ I think much better to be explicit. We don't know what type `input_subnetmask` is, and it is possible for example that a valid mask representing `0.0.0.0` might be falsy.